# How do I get a Docker Gitlab CI runner to access Git on its parent host?

Tags: docker, gitlab

Gitlab is setup on our internal network at http://gitlab

Docker containers on the same machine can't connect to it.

How do I configure docker so that it knows gitlab is its parent?

---

The problem exhibits itself when Gitlab CI attempts to run a build (inside a Docker container):

> Cloning into '/builds/ns/project'... fatal: unable to access
>   'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxx@gitlab/ns/project.git/': Couldn't
>   resolve host 'gitlab'

I've tried adding the network's DNS servers to `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker` to no avail.

Answer (score 14):

According to the [GitLab CI Runner Advanced configuration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runnersdocker-section), you can try to play with the `extra_hosts` param in your GitLab CI runner. 
In `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` :

```
[[runners]]
  url = "http://gitlab/ci"
  token = "TOKEN"
  name = "my_runner"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "tcp://<DOCKER_DAEMON_IP>:2375"
    image = "..."
    ...
    extra_hosts = ["gitlab:192.168.0.39"]
```

With this example, when inside the container running the test git will try to clone from *gitlab*, it will use the `192.168.0.39` as IP for this hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the container dns with the `--dns` flag to `docker run` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings), but it should use the host dns by default.

Answer (score 0):

In case your Gitlab installation also runs as a Docker container, just linking your gitlab-runner to the gitlab container should work:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always --link gitlab \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

This way Docker takes care of making the host 'gitlab' available inside gitlab-runner.