# add hosts redirection in docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I use gitlab in a Virtual machine . And I will use gitlab-ci (in the same VM), with docker .

For access to my gitlab, I use the domain git.local ( redirect to my VM on my computer, redirect to the 127.0.0.1 in my VM ).

And when I launch the tests, the test return :

> fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxx@git.local/thib3113/ESCF.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'git.local'

So My question is: How add a redirection for git.local to the container IP ? I see the `arg -h <host>` for docker, but I don't know how to tell gitlab to use this argument. Or maybe a configuration for tell docker to use the container dns?

I see this: [How do I get a Docker Gitlab CI runner to access Git on its parent host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185388/how-do-i-get-a-docker-gitlab-ci-runner-to-access-git-on-its-parent-host)
but same problem, I don't know how add argument :/ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Docker Gitlab CI runner to access Git on its parent host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185388/how-do-i-get-a-docker-gitlab-ci-runner-to-access-git-on-its-parent-host)

Answer (score 24):

According to the [GitLab CI Runner Advanced configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section), you can try to play with the `extra_hosts` param in your GitLab CI runner.
In `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` :

```
[[runners]]
  url = "http://localhost/ci"
  token = "TOKEN"
  name = "my_runner"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "tcp://<DOCKER_DAEMON_IP>:2375"
    image = "..."
    ...
    extra_hosts = ["localhost:192.168.0.39"]
```

With this example, when inside the container running the test git will try to clone from *localhost*, it will use the `192.168.0.39` as IP for this hostname.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use dns in docker use dns-gen follow these simple steps by this step you can assign host name to multi docker containers.
1. First know your docker IP by Publishing this command

`/sbin/ifconfig docker0 | grep "inet" | head -n1 | awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d: -f2`

2. now note the output ip and time to start dns-gen container(ps: don't forget to add docker ip you get by issuing above command before :53:53)

`docker run --detach \
  --name dns-gen \
  --publish dockerip:53:53/udp \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jderusse/dns-gen`

3. Last thing: Register you new DnsServer in you resolv.conf

`echo "nameserver dockerip" | sudo tee --append /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
`sudo resolvconf -u`

Now you should be able to access your docker container in browser :-  http://containername.docker

Hope it works.. Thanks..

`Shubhankit`