# GitLab CI script needs entry in /etc/hosts

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab CI docker runner to execute my automated tests when I push. One of my tests requires a custom entry in /etc/hosts. I can't figure out how to get the entry into that file.

Here's basically what my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like:

```
before_script:
  - cat /etc/hosts   # for debugging
  - ...              # install app dependencies
specs:
  script:
    - rspec          # <- a test in here fails without the /etc/hosts entry
```

All my tests pass, except for the one that requires that `/etc/hosts` entry.

Let's say I'm trying to have the hostname `myhost.local` resolve to the IPv4 address `XX.XX.XX.XX`...

I tried using `extra_hosts` on the runner config, but it didn't seem to have any effect ([got idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242634/add-hosts-redirection-in-docker)):

`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "shell"
  url = "https://mygitlabinstance.com/"
  token = "THETOKEN"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]

[[runners]]
  name = "docker-ruby-2.5"
  url = "https://mygitlabinstance.com/"
  token = "THETOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.5"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    extra_hosts = ["myhost.local:XX.XX.XX.XX"]
  [runners.cache]
```

But the test still failed. The `cat /etc/hosts` shows that it's unchanged:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 ip-172-31-2-54.ec2.internal ip-172-31-2-54
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I figured I could just add the entry myself in a `before_script` line, but I don't seem to be able to execute anything with root privileges in the container:

```
before_script:
  - echo 'XX.XX.XX.XX myhost.local' >> /etc/hosts
  ...
```

But that just fails because the `gitlab-runner` user doesn't have permissions to write to that file. I tried to use `sudo`, but `gitlab-runner` can't do that either (`echo 'XX.XX.XX.XX myhost.local' | sudo tee --non-interactive --append /etc/hosts` --> `sudo: a password is required`)

So in summary, how can I get my container to have the host entry I need (or how can I execute a `before_script` command as root)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following statement is incorrect:

> *"But that just fails because the gitlab-runner user doesn't have permissions to write to that file."*

The gitlab-runner is not the user executing your `before_script`, it is the user that runs the container in which your job is executed.

You are using the [`ruby:2.5`](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/c9a4472a019d18aba1fdab6a63b96474b40ca191/2.5/stretch/Dockerfile) Docker image as far as I can tell and that does not contain any `USER` reference in its or its parents `Dockerfile`.

Try adding a `whoami` command right before your `echo 'XX.XX.XX.XX myhost.local' >> /etc/hosts` command to verify you are `root`.

### Update

If `gitlab-runner` is shown as the result of `whoami`the `docker-executor` is not used and instead a `shell-executor` has picked up the job.

Comment: Yeah, I did that actually -- to the `before_script` I added `whoami` and got `gitlab-runner`. I did `groups` too and got `gitlab-runner docker rvm`, in case that's relevant. The GitLab runner must be setting up a user to execute the builds, right?

Comment: Eureka! Your answer helped me figure it out... Indeed I was *trying* to use the ruby:2.5 docker image, but as you correctly pointed out, that image doesn't have the `gitlab-runner` user. So why was `whoami` showing that? Because the shell runner was running the jobs, not the docker runner! I missed the fact that the project would default to the shell runner, despite having both available. I configured it to use the Docker runner and added the appropriate `image:` and the now-necessary `services: - postgres:9.4` to `gitlab-ci.yml` and it works! If you update your answer, I'll give you credit :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `config.toml` on your Gitlab CI runner, you can add a setting to the config.toml so you can achieve this without touching /etc/hosts.

```
[runners.docker]
# ... other settings ...
  extra_hosts = ["myhost.local:xx.xx.xx.xx"]
```

You can read more about the `extra_hosts` configuration here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section

Comment: The user already has this line in the config.toml as he shows in the answer. So this answer does not add anything new.