# Add to /etc/hosts in docker executor for gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Looking for help on this one. Am quite new in gitlab-ci, although bit experienced with docker.

All my attempts at getting my docker executor to build successfully is failing at:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.1.0 (081978aa)
  on my-runner 28d98f88
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Using locally found image version due to if-not-present pull policy
Using docker image sha256:9c33e070d450c33d0fda38016a1c454fcf296efc5af773d88fb5a5d17a99affc for docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using locally found image version due to if-not-present pull policy
Using docker image sha256:8f769f924e650ea5f873bede823add9e33aa6c74a2b2dd8ccd54c2c9e97ce1d3 for docker:latest ...
Running on runner-28d98f88-project-9-concurrent-0 via gitlab.home...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/root/gocryptme'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@cicd.home/root/gocryptme.git/': Could not resolve host: cicd.home
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

In short:

> Could not resolve host: cicd.home

Have tried all suggestions i've come across so far.

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_CI_IMAGE: cicd.home:4567/root/cidemo:cicd

before_script:
  - whoami
  - echo '10.11.0.130 cicd.home' >> /etc/hosts

build-image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $DOCKER_CI_IMAGE .
    - docker push $DOCKER_CI_IMAGE
```

For sure the before_script: section does not yield expected outputs.

Here is my config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "my-runner"
  url = "https://cicd.home/"
  token = "28d98f88b621865293c49c7fadfc5d"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw"]
    shm_size = 0
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
  [runners.cache]
```

To me it seems the procedure to add to /etc/hosts is not working here.

Comment: cicd.home is a private gitlab-ci instance along with docker registry

Comment: Where does that IP address come from?  (Are you running this on some cloud service, like AWS or GCP or Azure?)

Comment: @DavidMaze, this is a private installation and not on a cloud service. cicd.home is a VM on my machine running gitlab and hosting docker registry.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this same problem. I think the `before_script` will run as part of the job, *after* the clone. The clone happens before the jobs. So adding to `/etc/hosts` in the `before_script` will not help because the clone is attempted before the `before_script` starts.

Comment: This answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34709445/4476484. You can just add an `extra_hosts` line to your `config.toml` file within the docker instance, which you can access like this: run `sudo docker exec -it gitlab-runner /bin/bash` to start a shell inside docker, run `apt-get update` to update the image, then `apt-get install vim`, then use vim to edit the file, then `exit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add hosts redirection in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242634/add-hosts-redirection-in-docker)

Answer (score 4):

In your `config.toml` on your Gitlab CI runner, you can add a setting to the config.toml so you can achieve this without touching /etc/hosts. You could

```
[runners.docker]
# ... other settings ...
  extra_hosts = ["cicd.home:10.11.0.130"]
```

You can read more about the `extra_hosts` configuration here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section